# How can I create an image of my Ubuntu 12.10 to install on another device?

Tags: 12.10, backup, clone

Last week I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop and now I have my system more or less configured as I like.

I would like to know how can I create an image of the system that I can use to install Ubuntu in another computer as I currently have it in my laptop.

What do you think is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a customised Live CD with [this guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization). As it said [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/) is an easier way to customise the Live CD.

If you really want to create a Live CD from what you are using, you can [follow this guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch).